# Bash Script with MySQL query and Variables

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I am trying to write a small bash script that creates some mysql tables and assigns then to a new user:

```
[...]

DBUser='UserA'
VarA='BlaA'
VarB='BlaB'
VarC='BlaC'

[...]

MYSQL_PWD=`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysql -uadmin <<MYSQL_SCRIPT
create database `${VarA}` character set = 'utf8';
create database `${VarB}` character set = 'utf8';
create database `${VarC}` character set = 'utf8';
create user 'seafile'@'localhost' identified by '${DBUser}';
SET PASSWORD FOR '${DBUser}'@'localhost' = '${dbpw}';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `${VarA}`.* to `${DBUser}`@localhost;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `${VarB}`.* to `${DBUser}`@localhost;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `${VarC}`.* to `${DBUser}`@localhost;
MYSQL_SCRIPT

[...]
```

Result at the moment is:

```
testinstall: line 93: BlaA: command not found
testinstall: line 93: BlaB: command not found
testinstall: line 93: BlaC: command not found
testinstall: line 93: BlaA: command not found
testinstall: line 93: BlaB: command not found
testinstall: line 93: BlaC: command not found
testinstall: line 93: UserA: command not found
testinstall: line 93: BlaC: command not found
testinstall: line 93: UserA: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character set = 'utf8'' at line 1
```

How can I set the MYSQL_SCRIPT part correctly to use the Variables?

EDIT: thank @AndrewBone Thank you, the issue with command not found it gone by removing the "`". Now I still got the issue with the "character set = 'utf8'"

```
#create database ${VarA} character set = 'utf8';
#ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-db character set = utf8' at line 1
```

If I do it directly on mysql it works:

```
create database `bla1` character set = 'utf8';
#Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: The backticks mean you are trying to run your variables as commands

Comment: @AndrewBone thx that helped

Now only need to get the syntax for character right ;)

Comment: Not sure, but checkout out the MySQL docs, it does not seem like you would need to quote `utf8` (and the `=` is optional).